# Centering label with constraints in XCode Interface Builder

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm trying to center a label in the Interface Builder in XCode 6. Here's what I do:

1. Click on 'Hello World' label and add height and width constraint
2. Click on the same label and click on the 'Align' constraint. Check the Horizontal and Vertical align in container.
3. When I run it, the label is in the top-left corner. Why isn't it centered?

Below are some images of what I'm looking at:

[image]

[image]

[image]